# eclipse ide content assist in java script

Tags: eclipse

> Hi 
>   I installed the last version of eclipse idea for java developer 
>   I have problem in java script content assist 
>   do not work it
>    `Please help me`

Comment: Java and Javascript are different programming languages. Eclipse for Java developers doesn't include Javascript support.

Comment: Java and Javascript are different programming languages. Yes i Know

Comment: i want in script tag have content assist in jsp page without use of codmix or other plugin

Comment: Look for Eclipse for Javascript and not Eclipse for Java